# How to get UID of document in Cloud Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uid

Currently, my app is looping through all the documents in a collection in firebase, however I need to know which UID the data is from so that I can add to it later. Is there a way to find this out and if not, what are other alternative approaches that I can go about to accomplish this. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get `posts` with `id`:

```
let docQuery = this._db.collection('communityProgramPost')


const response = await docQuery.get();

const posts = response.docs.map(doc => {
  const post = doc.data();
  post.id = doc.id;
  return post;
});
```

Note that you're explicitly creating an id property on `post` and assigning it the value from `doc.id`. Simply returning `doc.data()` will not get you the `id`!

Answer (score 0):

See the example on this documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
>     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
>         if let err = err {
>             print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
>         } else {
>             for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
>                 print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
>             }
>         }
> }
> ```

You're looking for the `documentID` member of the `DocumentSnapshot` objects.